# perl script adds extra curly brackets

Tags: linux, perl

Following script, I'm using which performs everything well except it adds three extra curly brackets at the end of file.

`abc.jso` contains many lines where few lines have only opening/closing curly brackets (In case, this information helps)

I tried by making `print $a " $var";` instead of `print $a "$var";`. In short I added space in front of this `print` & it worked.

```
open (my $a,'+<',"abc.jso") or die $!;
my @lines=<$a>;
seek $a,0,0;
    while (@lines) {
        my $var = shift @lines;
        if ($var=~ /^\s*\"(netlist|filelist)\" : \".*$blk.*\",/) {
            print $a "            \"netlist\" : \"/t98/pnr/work/$blk"."_rk/run/dc/$blk"."_post_dft.v\",\n";
            $count++;
            print "Netlist got replaced\n";
        }
        elsif ($var=~ /^\s*\"spf\" : \".*$blk.*\"/) {
            print $a "            \"spf\" : \"/t98/scan/atpg/t98_1.0/spf/$blk".".scan_compress.spf\"\n";
            $count++;
            print "SPF got replaced\n";
        }
        else {
            print $a "$var";
        }
    }
close($a);
```

Can someone explain, why it is happening? Is there any such corner case of text handling that I'm not aware of?

Comment: If, as it appears, this file contains JSON data, you should be using a module like [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) to parse its contents (Perhaps read with [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper)) and manipulate the resulting data structure, instead of trying to use regular expressions on individual lines.

Answer (score 2):

Having some sample input and output would help but let me take a guess. Try truncating the file by the seek:

`truncate $a,0;
seek $a,0,0;`

Without the truncate you will be overwriting what was there before. This works if you write more information than you read but not so good if you write less than you read.